# Spring boot JWT Role authorization without Authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

With my limited knowledge in spring security , I am trying to implement role-based authorisation to the REST endpoints of my spring boot application.My application authentication is done by an external system. I  need to implement authorisation only in my context.I have multiple REST endpoints. These endpoints access need to be restricted according to the role that is coming in the jwt token.I need to know is there any way I can skip the authentication somehow in spring security. I prefer implementing this using annotation

`@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('USER', 'ADMIN')")` .

I have written a filter to extract the role details(Profile class contains the role info)

```
Optional.ofNullable(claims.get(USER_PROFILE).as(Profile.class));
```

But I'm not sure how to skip authentication and only implement authorisation. Can anyone provide me with a sample code or web links where I can refer for the solution?

Comment: read the chapter on "oauth2 resource server" in the spring security documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html. There it will tell you how to enable the handling of JWTs and then how to extracct authorities manually from the JWT and map these to specific roles https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction

Answer (score 1):

read the chapter on "oauth2 resource server" in the spring security documentation

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html.

There it will tell you how to enable the handling of JWTs and then how to extract authorities manually from the JWT and map these to specific roles

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction

Enabling the handling of JWTs in spring security

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
    return http.build();
}
```

Extracting authorities from the jwt and mapping these to roles

```
@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");

    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);
    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
}
```

These are just examples, they will not solve your problem, but if you read the docs, you will probably figure it out.

Here is a link to a github project with a full implementation and a blog post

https://github.com/Tandolf/spring-security-jwt-demo

Comment: It actually (almost) solves his problem: `anyRequest().authenticated()`  in conf ensures that authentication was performed and roles should be mapped from the access-token by an authentication converter. Only `@EnableMethodSecurity` is missing in this answer to perform the authorization with annotations ont components methods. Also, I think my tutorials cover more use cases (including advanced access-control) and simpler solutions: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials

Comment: and i never claimed it will solve the question, which you seem to think.

Comment: I think you claimed “will not solve your problem", and I think it almost does, but this are just opinions. I will not have more discussions with you and will carefully avoid your answers and comments from now on. Have a good day too.